# Can't access Firestore docs data after getting the doc object

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch a single field value from a doc in a collection (stored in Firestore).
The following function is called (by the triggered function) to perform this query and return the result.

Firestore data structure:
[image: Firestore data structure]

After I fetch the query result into `helper_token` object - I cannot access the DATA (fields) in it.
I tried many things, including:

```
helper_token[0].device_token;
helper_token.data().device_token;
JSON.stringify(helper_token);
```

Nothing works for me.
The log always shows results like these:

```
helper_token = {}
helper_token = undefined
```

What am I missing? **how can I get the `device_token` based on `user`?**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); //required to access the FB RT DB
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

function getHelperToken(helperId) {
    //Get token from Firestore
    const tokensRef = db.collection('tokens');
    const helper_token = tokensRef.where('user', '==', 'TM1EOV4lYlgEIly0cnGHVmCnybT2').get();
    if (helper_token.empty) {
        functions.logger.log('helper_token EMPTY');
    }
    functions.logger.log('helper_token=' + JSON.stringify(helper_token));

    return helper_token.device_token;
};
```

For completeness, adding here the full calling function to the above function:

```
//DB triggered function - upon writing a child in the HElpersInvitations reference
exports.sendHelperInvitation = functions.database.ref('/HelpersInvitations/{helper_invitation_id}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

        const helperId = snapshot.val().helperId;
        const title = snapshot.val().title;
        const body = snapshot.val().body;
        
        //Get the helper token by Id
        functions.logger.log('HelperID=' + helperId);
        functions.logger.log('getHelperToken=' + getHelperToken(helperId));
        const helper_token2 = getHelperToken(helperId);
        //Notification payload
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: title,
                body: body,
                icon: 'default',
                click_action: 'com.skillblaster.app.helperinvitationnotification' 
            }
        }
        
        //    //Send the notification
            functions.logger.log('helper_token [BEFORE sendToDevice]=' + helper_token2);
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(helper_token2, payload);


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that the `get()` call is asynchornous and also that you get a list of documents and not a single `doc`. Can you try it with this code:

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin"); //required to access the FB RT DB
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

async function getHelperToken(helperId) {
  //Get token from Firestore
  const tokensRef = db.collection("tokens");
  const helperTokens = await tokensRef
    .where("user", "==", "TM1EOV4lYlgEIly0cnGHVmCnybT2")
    .get();
  let helper_token = "";

  helperTokens.forEach((token) => {
    helper_token = token.data();
  });

  functions.logger.log("helper_token=" + JSON.stringify(helper_token));

  return helper_token.device_token;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
Unfortunately, the async nature of this function does not return anything in time to the calling function. The logger statement is not even reached.

Comment: How to you call the function?

Comment: const helper_token2 = getHelperToken(helperId); - see edit to the original question for the full calling function code

Comment: You need to call it like this `helper_token2 = await getHelperToken(helperId); `

Comment: Thank you, Tarik. But await is only available in async functions. This is a DB-triggered function.

Comment: We made that function async with `async function getHelperToken`

Comment: Yes, but the CALLING function isn't. It is triggered by DB updates. I can't add "await" to the call.

Comment: Can you pls show me the calling function.

Comment: It's all up here in the original question. I added everything - including the calling function

Comment: Is there the latest version? To call `await getHelperToken` you would need to make your caller function also async. Did you do that. Could you pls show how far you are with your current code pls.

Answer (score 0):

As the `get()` call in Firestore is asynchronous you need to use an asynchronous function. You can go through [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) to know more about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous.  Next when we query with the `where` clause in Firestore we get a list of documents even if there is only one document in the list. So we have to run a for loop to get the document inside the list of documents. Now as you are  returning the value from an asynchronous function the return value will be a promise in pending state. So to get the value from the promise we need to use the `then()` block while calling the function.

Also I think the parameter `helperId` you are using in the function definition is not used anywhere in the function. Though it will not make a difference I would suggest you remove it if it is not required in the function.

So consider using the following code -

```
const admin = require(‘firebase-admin’);
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
 
async function getHelperToken() {
   //Get token from Firestore
   const tokensRef = db.collection(‘tokens’);
   const helper_token = await tokensRef.where(‘user’, ‘==’, ‘TM1EOV4lYlgEIly0cnGHVmCnybT2’).get();
 
   let helper_token_needed;
   helper_token.forEach((token) => {
     helper_token_needed = token.data();
   });
    console.log(helper_token_needed.device_token);
   return helper_token_needed.device_token;
 }
 
//when calling to the function use then() block to get the value as a promise is returned from asynchronous function
getHelperToken().then((value)=>{console.log(value)});
```

Comment: Thank you Prabir.
I made this function async, but the calling function is not async (it is DB-triggered - see above), therefore I can't use "await" there. btw the helperId argument will replace the hard-coded Id in the "where" query.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question and clarifying the use of `helperId`. Can you please confirm if you are using the returned value from the DB triggered function anywhere. Or else calling `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(helper_token2, payload)` only will do your work?